# Can I disable/enable lazy loading selectively in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

In Entity Framework it was is evidently possible to disable lazy loading [for individual properties](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx):

> To turn off lazy loading for a particular property, do not make it virtual.

But in EF Core I get this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Property 'DBO.Property' is not virtual. 'UseChangeTrackingProxies' requires all entity types to be public, unsealed, have virtual properties, and have a public or protected constructor. 'UseLazyLoadingProxies' requires only the navigation properties be virtual.

(This is thrown when setting `ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` in my DbContext-derived constructor.)

I'm using the second method mentioned in this error (with the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package):

```
// in my class derived from DbContext
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    builder.UseLazyLoadingProxies(true);
}
```

Can I turn off lazy loading for a single property in EF Core?

Comment: To look at the problem from a different angle, Why do you need lazy loading enabled for everything except for a particular property?

Comment: @StevePy I'm transitioning the system from a design that doesn't use automatic lazy loading to one that does*, and (1) it's easier to transition one class at a time rather than all at once, and (2) it's unclear at this time that I would want literally every navigation property to support lazy-loading. (* the old design is complicated and I'm intentionally leaving out key details.)

Comment: Sounds complicated. Not sure I can think of a scenario where I'd want to do something like that. Normally the re-factoring I do goes somewhat the other way, from a system that is relying heavily on lazy loading (resulting in performance issues) into something that does not. That's not a case of disabling/removing lazy loading but more transitioning to projection. Lazy loading makes for a good failsafe, not really a good design....

Comment: If your current system relies too heavily on eager loading large complex models all of the time resulting in huge Cartesian Products then I can recommend looking at bringing in projections to ViewModels/DTOs as an alternative to trying to selectively lazy load bits.  It's not an insignificant change, but it is something that can be brought in incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

You can try follow this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy

> Lazy loading without proxies

It seems like it can be defined for specific properties with ILazyLoader.

Comment: This article implies that a constructor like `private DBO(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)` lets you "take over" the lazy loading process so that the properties no longer need to be virtual. But this doesn't work for me; the exception for that DBO class still occurs after adding the additional constructor, and even after customizing the properties.